# How to create a preloader mask with CSS/JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css-transitions, preloader

I'm trying to recreate a part of the preloader of [this website](https://www.bertani.net/) - specifically the part where the "red box" swipe ups and reveals what's beneath.

I tried playing with CSS transitions, but I can't seem to find a solution - or even an example - to it. How could I do it without libraries?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+css+preloader+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.